# Assert that class recovered through runtime reflection is a subclass of another class

Tags: scala, reflection

I am trying to call a method:

```
def doSomething[A <: Super : ClassTag] : B = { ... }
```

The method only takes a type parameter.

I have an `AnyRef` object and I've recovered its class at runtime. I know that the class of the object is a subclass of `Super` and I want to call `doSomething`.

Is there a way to call `doSomething` with the object's class as the parameter? Can I assert to the compiler that the class I recover at runtime is a subclass of `Super`?

I am not concerned about this failing at runtime in the case where my object is not a subclass of `Super` for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect this should work:

```
val obj: AnyRef = ...
val tag = ClassTag(obj.getClass).asInstanceOf[ClassTag[_ <: Super]]
doSomething(tag)
```

If not, you can lie to the compiler even more:

```
val tag = ClassTag(obj.getClass).asInstanceOf[ClassTag[Super]]
```

(since the cast is really a no-op, and even though the compiler now thinks `tag` is a `ClassTag[Super]` and will infer `Super` type argument to `doSomething`, it'll get the correct class at the runtime.)

Comment: In that case I'd prefer the first one since `tag` really _is_ an instance of `ClassTag[_ <: Super]` (assuming "the class I recover at runtime is a subclass of Super" holds) but not of `ClassTag[Super]`.